# Can I place 'and' in When statement in scenario description? (gherkin)

Tags: unit-testing, cucumber, gherkin

Can I place such scenario step in feature:

`When user enters Upload page, downloads template, fills it with data and then uploads it to system
Then ...`

Or maybe I should create two steps from previous step? I wonder how strictly I should keep with "and".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way it's written in your question, I think it would be better off as

```
When user enters Upload page
And downloads template
And fills it with data 
And then uploads it to system
```

As they sound like important parts of the test.  However, if the separate steps aren't important to the test, then it might be better to write it as

```
When a user uploads a completed template
```

In general, scenarios that have too many lines are harder to read and not as nice to work with.  So, if the individual steps are relevant to the test, then leave them on their own lines.  But if they aren't important to the test, don't be afraid to squish them into a more general step, but try to actually make the step more general, rather than just putting all of the separate steps on one line.